# How to add custom class on the menu block using twig?

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I'm new in Drupal 8 and i'm trying to display my primary menu block using `twig` as below

```
 {% if page.primary_menu %}
   {{ page.primary_menu }}
 {% endif %}
```

which gives me like this

```
<ul class="sm menu-base-theme" id="main-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="/drupal8/" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="is-active">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/drupal8/" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="is-active">Home</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add my custom class attributes on `ul`  and `a` elements to get the menu like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="main-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="#about" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="page-scroll">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#home" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="page-scroll">Home</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can i add my custom class on the menu? If you have any idea about this problem then please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating template file called "menu--main.html" in your theme's template folder.

Then in place below code in that file:

```
{% import _self as menus %}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
```

```
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu', 'nav', 'navbar-nav','navbar-right') }}>
```

```
    {% else %}
```

```
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass('dropdown-menu') }}>
```

```
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded %}
```

```
    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('expanded', 'dropdown') }}>
    <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="page-scroll">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

```
      {% else %}
        
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if item.below %}
        {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav', 'navbar-nav'), menu_level + 1) }}
      {% endif %}
```

```
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

```
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

This will add the class "ul"

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Menu Link Attribute](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) module which allows you to add class, id, etc.. to your menu item.

> This module allows you to add attributes to your menu links.

Hence, you can customize your menu item, using those added attributes.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

May you can use hooks:

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for menu.html.twig.
*/
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['menu_name'] == 'main') {
    if (!isset($variables['attributes']['class'])) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'] = [];
    }
    $variables['attributes']['class'] = array_merge($variables['attributes']['class'], ['my-main-menu']);  }
}
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file